# IntelliJ Debugger: Count how many times a function is called

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, methods, profiling

I want to count how many times a function is called overall in my program. The method is called in different objects and I dont want to pass one variable through and let them all add to it.
Is there a feature in the IntelliJ Debugger that's counts how often a function is called overall?

Specificially, my program is a search-tree algorithm for a graph-problem and I want to count, how many different branches the generated search-tree has. Each of these branches corresponds to a call of the mentioned function.

Comment: Add a static variable that is incremented. If you use threads, consider using a [LongAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html).

Comment: Yea I know, but there has to be something cleaner than that.

Comment: @Morinator does [this answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206893895-Some-questions-on-debugging-in-Idea-?page=1#community_comment_206985409) help?

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks in advance @CrazyCoder.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

1. Set up a breakpoint
2. Uncheck the suspend
3. Check the "Breakpoint hit" message
4. After running the code, search the printed message and find the count.

Comment: I guess technically this answers it, but I want to analyze a searchtree-algorithm, where I'd need to count the calls for many different functions. I feel like this doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that not based on Intellij IDE, I found a tool [byteman](https://byteman.jboss.org/) recently, it should be able to allow you to inject your code snippet into a dedicated Class method, so you can count the number of calls systematically.